# Duplicate vote checking

Tags: python, beginner, django

I am new to Django and added a vote duplicate check to the tutorial application. I set a cookie in the vote view:

```
cookie_name = 'voted'
cookie_pattern = '^(\d-?)+$'
# ...
def vote(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    # ...
    # Set duplicate vote cookie.
    half_year = timedelta(weeks=26)
    expires = datetime.utcnow() + half_year
    if cookie and re.match(cookie_pattern, cookie):
        redirect.set_cookie(cookie_name, "{}-{}".format(cookie, question.id), expires=expires)
    else:
        redirect.set_cookie(cookie_name, question.id, expires=expires)
```

And then check for the cookie in the detail and vote view:

```
def has_voted(cookie, question_id):
    """Checks for question_id in cookie"""
    return cookie and \
        re.match(cookie_pattern, cookie) and \
        question_id in list(map(int, cookie.split('-')))


class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'polls/detail.html'

    # ...
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # Check duplicate vote cookie
        cookie = self.request.COOKIES.get(cookie_name)
        if has_voted(cookie, self.object.id):
            context['voted'] = True
        return context


def vote(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    cookie = request.COOKIES.get(cookie_name)
    if has_voted(cookie, question.id):
        return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {
            'question': question,
            'voted': True,
        })
```

What can be improved in this implementation?